# Defining group with multiple index value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping

I want to do the Bartlett test with the following data

| Sample | RdRp | E | N | Day | Temp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 103307.0863 | 118355.7563 | 288771.7766 | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 107374.2944 | 119575.9188 | 266808.8528 | 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 102086.9239 | 119169.198 | 278197.0355 | 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 103994.1128 | 115458.0308 | 251387.3436 | 3 | -20 |
| 5 | 103584.6872 | 114639.1795 | 253843.8974 | 3 | -20 |
| 6 | 106450.6667 | 108497.7949 | 255072.1744 | 3 | -20 |
| 7 | 105704.8475 | 120569.5917 | 251049.0129 | 3 | -80 |
| 8 | 107769.3953 | 117679.2248 | 249397.3747 | 3 | -80 |
| 9 | 104466.1189 | 123459.9587 | 253113.5607 | 3 | -80 |
| 10 | 105046.6462 | 104636.3077 | 260975.2615 | 5 | 4 |
| 11 | 105867.3231 | 109970.7077 | 266720 | 5 | 4 |
| 12 | 101763.9385 | 107098.3385 | 263026.9538 | 5 | 4 |
| 13 | 102250.4304 | 109121.0127 | 246532.6582 | 5 | -20 |
| 14 | 103462.8861 | 123670.481 | 238045.4684 | 5 | -20 |
| 15 | 96996.4557 | 113162.5316 | 254615.6962 | 5 | -20 |
| 16 | 104711.3684 | 113938.807 | 242320.5614 | 5 | -80 |
| 17 | 104310.1754 | 108723.2982 | 251949.193 | 5 | -80 |
| 18 | 97891.08772 | 118351.9298 | 249943.2281 | 5 | -80 |
| 19 | 101149.3671 | 100744.7696 | 253682.6127 | 8 | 4 |
| 20 | 97507.98987 | 102363.1595 | 267034.3291 | 8 | 4 |
| 21 | 101553.9646 | 102767.757 | 258537.7823 | 8 | 4 |
| 22 | 97977.74359 | 113555.7949 | 245969.2308 | 8 | -20 |
| 23 | 102897.1282 | 113145.8462 | 255808 | 8 | -20 |
| 24 | 109046.359 | 115195.5897 | 256627.8974 | 8 | -20 |
| 25 | 105661.883 | 110944.9771 | 247899.0331 | 8 | -80 |
| 26 | 106474.6667 | 111757.7608 | 250743.7761 | 8 | -80 |
| 27 | 105661.883 | 116228.0712 | 258871.6132 | 8 | -80 |
| 28 | 101923.4694 | 112931.2041 | 270301.0408 | 1 | 25 |
| 29 | 103554.2449 | 110077.3469 | 259293.3061 | 1 | 25 |
| 30 | 104369.6327 | 113338.898 | 242577.8571 | 1 | 25 |
| 31 | 58826.07634 | 57158.11705 | 130995.827 | 3 | 25 |
| 32 | 61185.6285 | 56425.84224 | 168016.3868 | 3 | 25 |
| 33 | 60860.17303 | 53496.743 | 172084.5802 | 3 | 25 |

And I made the following working code.

```
stab=read.csv("519stability.csv")

bartlett.test(data=stab, RdRp ~ Day, subset = Temp == -80)
bartlett.test(data=stab, RdRp ~ Day, subset = Temp == -20)
bartlett.test(data=stab, RdRp ~ Day, subset = Temp == 4)
bartlett.test(data=stab, RdRp ~ Day, subset = Temp == 25)

bartlett.test(data=stab, E ~ Day, subset = Temp == -80)
bartlett.test(data=stab, E ~ Day, subset = Temp == -20)
bartlett.test(data=stab, E ~ Day, subset = Temp == 4)
bartlett.test(data=stab, E ~ Day, subset = Temp == 25)

bartlett.test(data=stab, N ~ Day, subset = Temp == -80)
bartlett.test(data=stab, N ~ Day, subset = Temp == -20)
bartlett.test(data=stab, N ~ Day, subset = Temp == 4)
bartlett.test(data=stab, N ~ Day, subset = Temp == 25)
```

This code produces what I want. But is there smart and simple code with some library (dplyr, reshape2, etc.)?

The point is defining a group with two index values; Day and Temp.

---

Edit
I add my data with dput() here.

```
structure(list(Sample = 1:33, RdRp = c(103307.0863, 107374.2944, 
102086.9239, 103994.1128, 103584.6872, 106450.6667, 105704.8475, 
107769.3953, 104466.1189, 105046.6462, 105867.3231, 101763.9385, 
102250.4304, 103462.8861, 96996.4557, 104711.3684, 104310.1754, 
97891.08772, 101149.3671, 97507.98987, 101553.9646, 97977.74359, 
102897.1282, 109046.359, 105661.883, 106474.6667, 105661.883, 
101923.4694, 103554.2449, 104369.6327, 58826.07634, 61185.6285, 
60860.17303), E = c(118355.7563, 119575.9188, 119169.198, 115458.0308, 
114639.1795, 108497.7949, 120569.5917, 117679.2248, 123459.9587, 
104636.3077, 109970.7077, 107098.3385, 109121.0127, 123670.481, 
113162.5316, 113938.807, 108723.2982, 118351.9298, 100744.7696, 
102363.1595, 102767.757, 113555.7949, 113145.8462, 115195.5897, 
110944.9771, 111757.7608, 116228.0712, 112931.2041, 110077.3469, 
113338.898, 57158.11705, 56425.84224, 53496.743), N = c(288771.7766, 
266808.8528, 278197.0355, 251387.3436, 253843.8974, 255072.1744, 
251049.0129, 249397.3747, 253113.5607, 260975.2615, 266720, 263026.9538, 
246532.6582, 238045.4684, 254615.6962, 242320.5614, 251949.193, 
249943.2281, 253682.6127, 267034.3291, 258537.7823, 245969.2308, 
255808, 256627.8974, 247899.0331, 250743.7761, 258871.6132, 270301.0408, 
259293.3061, 242577.8571, 130995.827, 168016.3868, 172084.5802
), Day = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Temp = c(4L, 4L, 4L, -20L, -20L, -20L, -80L, 
-80L, -80L, 4L, 4L, 4L, -20L, -20L, -20L, -80L, -80L, -80L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, -20L, -20L, -20L, -80L, -80L, -80L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -33L))
```

Comment: You're essentially wanting to apply a function by group, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562656/calculate-the-mean-by-group . Instead of `mean`, you will do a `bartlett.test` - e.g.: `by(dat, dat$Temp, \(SD) bartlett.test(RdRp ~ Day, SD))` as one of the many options. I think that question would explain the process better than I could do by attempting to rewrite it.

Comment: Please provide your data as editable code, with `dput(data)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an `outer` approach, where you first put dependent variables and temperatures in vectors and define a bartlett skeleton in a `FUN`ction. Gives a matrix which can easily be `split`ted into a list. To know which one is which we should `setNames`.

```
dpv <- c('RdRp', 'E', 'N')
tmp <- c(-80, -20, 4,  25)
FUN <- Vectorize(\(x, y) 
                 bartlett.test(data=stab, as.formula(paste(x, '~ Day')), 
                               subset=Temp == y), 
                 SIMPLIFY=F)
    
res <- outer(dpv, tmp, FUN) |>
  split(rep(seq(tmp), each=length(dpv))) |>
  setNames(make.names(tmp))
```

##### Result

```
res$X.80  ## the first list element, temp -80
# [[1]]
# 
# Bartlett test of homogeneity of variances
# 
# data:  RdRp by Day
# Bartlett's K-squared = 5.1079, df = 2, p-value = 0.07777
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# 
#   Bartlett test of homogeneity of variances
# 
# data:  E by Day
# Bartlett's K-squared = 0.63384, df = 2, p-value = 0.7284
# 
# 
# [[3]]
# 
# Bartlett test of homogeneity of variances
# 
# data:  N by Day
# Bartlett's K-squared = 1.797, df = 2, p-value = 0.4072
```

**Note:** R > 4.1.* is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use loops:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

map(unique(stab$Temp), ~ bartlett.test(data=stab, RdRp ~ Day, subset = Temp==.x))
map(unique(stab$Temp), ~ bartlett.test(data=stab, E ~ Day, subset = Temp ==.x))
map(unique(stab$Temp), ~ bartlett.test(data=stab, N ~ Day, subset = Temp ==.x))
```

This may be simplified more with nested loops:

```
library(purrr)

formulas<-c('RdRp ~ Day', 'E ~ Day', 'N ~ Day')

map(formulas, function(form)
        map(unique(stab$Temp), ~ bartlett.test(data=stab,
                                               as.formula(form),
                                               subset = Temp == .x)))
```

I can not test this without a sample of your data as code, though.

Comment: Excellent! This must be what I want.  Now I need to learn how it works!

Comment: Glad I can help. If you think this is helpfull, please check here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Yau may try `lapply`

```
coln <- c("RdRp", "E", "N")
temps <- c(-80, -20, 4, 25)
lapply(coln, function(x) {
  lapply(temps, function(y){
    bartlett.test(stab[[x]] ~ stab$Day, subset = stab$Temp == y)
  })
  
})
```

Some part of results are like

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]

    Bartlett test of homogeneity of variances

data:  stab[[x]] by stab$Day
Bartlett's K-squared = 5.1079, df = 2, p-value = 0.07777


[[1]][[2]]

    Bartlett test of homogeneity of variances

data:  stab[[x]] by stab$Day
Bartlett's K-squared = 2.2096, df = 2, p-value = 0.3313
```